# how can I add a post identifier to my ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to add a post identifier to my ajax. Basically right now the way that I identify my post is by checking if one of the inputs is present. Here is the code:

```
   <input name="id" id="id" type="text">
```

If the input with name id is present posted then I execute my php code. Here is the code:

```
   if(isset($_POST['id'])){
```

The issue that I am having is that I want to put multiple id posts in the same page so I need to sort them to know what is post is doing. I want to add a post identifier.

```
   if(isset($_POST['addLogin'])){
```

How can I add a post identifier to this ajax function. Here is the code:

```
   $(function() {
   $("button#loginSubmit").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "",
   data: $('form.loginForm').serialize(),
```

I wanted to add something like a `{last_time:last_time}` How can I add post identifier?

Comment: `$('form.loginForm').serialize() + '&lasttime=444'`

Comment: Is that `$('form.loginForm').serialize() + '&addLogin=addLogin'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
data: { last_time : "test"}
```

Comment: Is that `data: { addLogin : "addLogin"}`